# Add PDF page in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf-generation, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I have an algorithm to create a PDF file, but I want just to add one pdf page at the end of existing pdf. Do any one has idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for merging pdf but using an other library:

[Merge PDF files on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553540/merge-pdf-files-on-ios)

Comment: thanks john but I don't want to redraw whole PDf again just want some logic to add the page at the last.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can read the old pdf file,and recontruct a new pdf file.I think.

Answer (score 0):

Up till now it's not possible to reopen and continue editing a PDF file . Only redraw whole PDf again .